# Adding 'rect' elements to blank svg canvas in d3 is failing on .data()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, polymer

I'm using Polymer to render some d3 charts. When the Polymer is initially rendered I only draw a graph with axes and no data, since the data comes later once the API calls succeed. However, when I get around to selecting the 'rect' elements in the svg, calling `data()` on that fails. Here's my code:

```js
dataChanged: function() {
    var data = this.data;
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = this.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = d3.isoParse(d.date);
    });

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
        .rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart).transition();

    var histogram = d3.histogram()
        .value(function(d) { return d.date; })
        .domain(x.domain())
        .thresholds(x.ticks(d3.timeMonth));

    var bins = histogram(data);

    y.domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.length; })]);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(bins)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", 1)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")";
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) -1 ; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });

    svg.select(".xAxis")
        .duration(300)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    svg.select(".yAxis")
        .duration(300)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
},
ready: function() {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = this.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(2010, 6, 3), new Date(2012, 0, 1)])
        .rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    // Add the SVG to my 'chart' div.    
    var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","yAxis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
 }
```

`ready()` gets called upon rendering, `dataChanged()` when the parent component passes a chunk of data down. Everything works fine until `svg.selectAll("rect").data(bins)` is called when it crashes with `Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data is not a function`. `bins` has the right data in it, so that's not empty. I know that there are no `rect` elements for it to select, but in the [example I followed here](https://leanpub.com/d3-t-and-t-v4/read#leanpub-auto-the-code-1) there are no `rect` elements prior to them being appended by this call anyway, so I'm confused as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the purpose of this line:

```
var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart).transition();
```

This would make `svg` a transition, your code is implying it should be selection.  So, just drop it the `.transition`:

```
var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart);

...

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(bins)
  ...
```

Comment: Ah, right, yeah, that did the trick. I wanted the new bars to use a transition when they came into existence. Now my code runs, but the rect bars aren't visible on the graph. Inspector shows me they have a height of 0x17, even though this is the svg: `<rect class="bar" x="1" transform="translate(0,24.06417112299465)" width="101" height="275.93582887700535"></rect>`...

Comment: `I wanted the new bars to use a transition when they came into existence`, the transition would be applied to the selection containing the bars then (the rects), not the svg container.  You'd also need to define how the transition would should work.  For you new problem, you'll have to update your question with a reproducible example (or at the very least a your data so I could reproduce your problem).  Not enough details to guess.

Comment: Righto. Made a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304317/rects-wont-show-up-on-d3-histogram