# Rects won't show up on d3 histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, polymer

I'm using Polymer to render some d3 charts. When the Polymer is initially rendered I only draw a graph with axes and no data, since the data comes later once the API calls succeed. However, when I get around to adding the 'rect' elements in the svg, despite them showing up in the Chrome devtools element inspector, they don't show up in the chart itself.

```js
dataChanged: function() {
    var data = this.data;
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = this.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = d3.isoParse(d.date);
    });

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
        .rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart);

    var histogram = d3.histogram()
        .value(function(d) { return d.date; })
        .domain(x.domain())
        .thresholds(x.ticks(d3.timeMonth));

    var bins = histogram(data);

    y.domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.length; })]);


    var t = d3.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(bins)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", 1)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")";
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) -1 ; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });

    svg.select(".xAxis")
        .transition(t)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    svg.select(".yAxis")
        .transition(t)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
},
ready: function() {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = this.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(2010, 6, 3), new Date(2012, 0, 1)])
        .rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    // Add the SVG to my 'chart' div.    
    var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","yAxis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
 }
```

`ready()` gets called upon rendering, `dataChanged()` when the parent component passes a chunk of data down.

The axes get rendered correctly, with the right transitions and the right dimensions, but the rects don't. They show up in the chrome element inspector with a 0x17 size, even though this is what they look like: `<rect class="bar" x="1" transform="translate(0,24.06417112299465)" width="101" height="275.93582887700535"></rect>`

Comment: What is `this.$.chart`?  Is it an SVG element?  My guess is that it's not and you are parenting your rect to an HTML element like a `<div>`...

Comment: `this.$.chart` is a div inside the Polymer `<template>` section that I want the chart to appear on. Does that have to be svg?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ready` function, you are grabbing your `div` creating an `svg` element adding a `g` element and then appending your axis to that `g`.

In your `dataChanged` function, you are grabbing your `div` and appending `rects` to it.

See the disconnect?  You can't parent `svg` to HTML.

In `ready` do this:

```
 var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart).append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("id", "canvas")
   .attr("transform",
         "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

In `dataChanged`:

```
var svg = d3.select("#canvas");
```

This will allow you to "find" the appropriate `g` to append your rects to.

Comment: This didn't do the trick... I don't see any rects in the page now, whereas I did when I was selecting `this.$.chart`. The `svg` variable when it was selecting on `#canvas` was pretty empty; its `_groups` variable is one array of length 1, which contains a `null`.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan, did you add this line when appending your `g`: `.attr("id", "canvas")`?

Comment: Yep. In the element inspector I see the `g` element has the `canvas` id, so I'm not sure why it's not selecting it. And the element definitely exists at the time of selection.

Comment: To be clear, when selecting the `#canvas` neither the x or y axis updated as they do when I select `this.$.chart`. I'm not sure why `d3.select` isn't working on ids; `this.$.canvas` doesn't work either.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan, can you create a reproducible example?  Not sure I can debug any further with so many unknowns.

Comment: I think it's all in the `select` call. For some reason, even with the `id` of the `g` element set to `canvas`, `d3.select('canvas')` or `d3.select(this.$.canvas)` don't work. It can't be anything to do with polymer's shadow-dom because `d3.select(this.$.chart) does work.

I can't do a reproducible example because jsfiddle doesn't have Polymer.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan, you are using `d3.select('#canvas')` right (note the #)?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan, there's plenty of example of getting [plunker to play nice with polymer](http://plnkr.co/edit/NQ4qGEoS24hia4numeLP?p=preview).

Comment: Yes I am using `d3.select("#canvas")`, but it doesn't work either. I tried the `this.$.canvas` form because it works with `this.$.chart`, while `"#chart"` doesn't work either.

Comment: I found a solution; I did `var svg2 = svg.select("#canvas")` and appended the rects to the svg2 variable. The x and y axis continue to happily be appended to the svg variable. I think this worked because it was able to directly select the `canvas` element from the already-selected `chart` parent.